# Java in XML: Recursively return nodes

Tags: java, xml, dom, recursion

I have a question concerning the parsing of nodes in XML for Java.

Following code:

```
public static String returnNodes(Node node, String node2) {
    // do something with the current node instead of System.out
    System.out.println("Test1: " + node.getNodeName());
    String result = "";

    result = node.getNodeName();
    // Just for testing purposes
    if (result.equals(node2)) {
        return "YES!";
    }

    if (!result.equals(node2)) {
        System.out.println("Test2");
        NodeList nodeList = node.getChildNodes();
        for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
            Node currentNode = nodeList.item(i);
            if (currentNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                //calls this method for all the children which is Element
                returnNodes(currentNode, node2);
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

I want to proof if `node2` equals the current `node` and - if it matches - return the value in a variable called result.
At the moment I just get the root element of my document if I called this method and I don't know why. However, "YES!" is never printed on my console although the `System.out.println("Test1: " + node.getNodeName());` prints "actor" if I'll call the method in this way:
`returnNodes(document.getFirstChild(), "actor");` - and so the result is always "log".

The xml-structure looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<log>
<published>2014-03-28T15:28:36.646Z</published>
<actor>
    <objectType>person</objectType>
    <id>e1b8948f-321e-78ca-d883-80500aae71b5</id>
    <displayName>anonymized</displayName>
</actor>
<verb>update</verb>
<object>
    <objectType>concept</objectType>
    <id>a1ad6ace-c722-ffa9-f58e-b4169acdb4e3</id>
    <content>time</content>
</object>
<target>
    <objectType>conceptMap</objectType>
    <id>4b8f69e3-2914-3a1a-454e-f4c157734bd1</id>
    <displayName>my first concept map</displayName>
</target>
<generator>
    <objectType>application</objectType>
    <url>http://www.golabz.eu/content/go-lab-concept-mapper</url>
    <id>c9933ad6-dd4a-6f71-ce84-fb1676ea3aac</id>
    <displayName>ut.tools.conceptmapper</displayName>
</generator>
<provider>
    <objectType>ils</objectType>
    <url>http://graasp.epfl.ch/metawidget/1/b387b6f</url>
    <id>10548c30-72bd-0bb3-33d1-9c748266de45</id>
    <displayName>unnamed ils</displayName>
</provider>
</log>
```

What do I have to change if I want to print out the nodes I need in this recursive manner?

Answer (score 0):

I want to answer my own question. The solution I was looking for is not really recursive, rather iterative, but leads to the same result I looked for.

```
public static String getNode(Document document, String search) {
    NodeList nodeList = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
    for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
        Node node = nodeList.item(i);
        if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE && node.getNodeName().equals(search)) {
            // do something with the current element
            return node.getNodeName();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```